# RNCookieManager & Flipper-Folly - Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'cmath' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

These days I'm upgrading the react-native application from version 0.61.5 to 0.68.2.
With a few modified Gradle files and minor configuration adjustments, the Android application is currently functioning without any issues. But the iOS application always provides me with some issues after changing the pod file.

I used react native upgrade helper  ([React Native Upgrade Helper 0.61.5 to 0.68.2](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.61.5&to=0.68.2)) for this upgrade.

my pod File as follows (react-native version 0.68.2 and react version 17.0.1)

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '11.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'HAnalytics' do

  config = use_native_modules!
  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  

  pod 'RNCPushNotificationIOS', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/push-notification-ios'

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'  

  pod 'react-native-camera', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-camera'

  pod 'RNDeviceInfo', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-device-info'

  pod 'react-native-document-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-document-picker'

  pod 'RNFileViewer', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-file-viewer'

  pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

  pod 'RNImageCropPicker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker'

  pod 'BVLinearGradient', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'

  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

  pod 'react-native-view-shot', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-view-shot'

  pod 'rn-fetch-blob', :path => '../node_modules/rn-fetch-blob'

  pod 'RNImageRotate', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-rotate'

  pod 'react-native-orientation-locker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-orientation-locker'

  pod 'react-native-netinfo', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo'

  pod 'RNKeychain', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-keychain'

  pod 'RNAWSCognito', :path => '../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js'

  pod 'tipsi-stripe', :path => '../node_modules/tipsi-stripe'

  pod 'react-native-webview', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-webview'

  pod 'react-native-biometrics', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-biometrics'

  target 'HAnalyticsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
  
  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end

end
```

Header Search Paths -:

[image]

Error -:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions I found for this,

1st solution is replace the "`react-native-cookie`" [URL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-cookie) which is deprecated dependency to "`@react-native-cookies/cookies`" [URL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-cookies/cookies) to this.

2nd solution is regenerate the iOS folder using following commands.

```
npm i react-native-eject
npm i @react-native-community/cli // if required use this.
react-native eject
```